# Question about Gauss Sums

Tags: number-theory, gauss-sums

I'm reading Davenport's *Multiplicative Number Theory*, specifically chapter 2 in which we calculate the sum
$$G=\sum_{m=1}^{q-1}\left(\frac{m}{q}\right)e_q(m)$$
where $e_q(m)=\exp(2\pi i m/q)$.
He writes,
$$G=_1\sum_{R}e_q(R)-\sum_N e_q(N)=_21+2\sum_R e_q(R)=_3\sum_{x=0}^{q-1}e_q(x^2)$$
where we sum over the quadratic residues mod $q$ (indexed by $R$) and subtract the non-residues (indexed by $N$).

I see how $=_1$ follows from the definition of the legendre symbol, but I fail to see how the next two equalities follow. Why are we able to add $1+2(residues)$? Ie, what happened to all of the subtractions? Then, why are we now able to change argument of $e_q$ into $x^2$?

Comment: Use $\sum_{m=0}^{q-1} e_q(m)=0$

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: $G=G+\sum_{m=0}^{q-1} e_q(m)$